# show different columns from different table with inner join

Tags: sql

Hi i have a lot of inner in a query but i can't print column in different table, for example:
where

```
Table A
id       f
-----------
xxx     gggg
bbb     kkkk

Table B
name    code
-----------
ccc     dddd
bbb     oooo
```

My code:

```
select A.id,A.F from (query1)as stima
join
(select B.name,B.code from B as aaaa query)as noome
on noome.code=stima.F;
```

But if i want put name columns of B table in 'select A.id,A.F' how can i do?
My output is id and colum F but i want output: id,F and name columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have a column in an inner query that you want to use in an outer query, you have to make sure the inner query selects it. It will then become part of the query block with the new alias you give it:

```
SELECT
  a.Name,
  a.SomethingElse,
  b.ColumnX,
  b.ColumnYYY
FROM
  (
    SELECT c.Name, d.SomethingElse FROM c JOIN d ON ..
  ) a
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT e.ColumnX, f.ColY as ColumnYYY FROM e JOIN f ON ..
  ) b
```

When they're in the *inner* queries the columns are like `d.SomethingElse` and `f.ColY` but when they pass outside of those brackets, they get a new alias, because they are part of the data block that is aliased by `a` or `b`, so you no longer refer to them as their inner names.. Particularly in the case of `f.ColY` it was renamed to `ColumnYYY` *and also* given a new "table" alias of `b`..

[image]

Comment: i have never used table renaming in this way. Thank you very much.

Comment: It helped me to stop thinking about them as tables, and just start thinking about them as "blocks of data with rows and columns" - mostly data starts out in a table, like C and D in my query above, and maybe C has 10 columns and D has 5, but then it gets joined, and only 2 of the columns are selected so 13 of the columns are gone, and now there is no C and D any more but a new block of data called A, with two columns.. and so it goes on.. It's "all just blocks of data" - JOINs make blocks wider, UNIONS make them taller, WHERE makes them shorter and SELECT  makes them narrower :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any columns from the tables of the from clause.

I think you need this:

```
select A.id,A.F, noome.name -- this
from (query1)as stima
join
(select B.name,B.code from B as aaaa query)as noome
on noome.code=stima.F;
```